Higher Degree Differential Equation
I'm having trouble with the development of this equation:
$$\sin{y'}-x=0 $$
If I solve the equation with this method, I don't have any problems.
$$\sin{y'}=x$$
$$y'=\arcsin{x}$$
$$\int dy=\int \arcsin{x} dx$$
$$y = x\,\arcsin\left(x\right)+\sqrt{1-{x}^{2}}+C$$
But if I try this way (relative to x)
$$p= \frac{dy}{dx} = y'$$
$$\sin{p}=x$$
Where
$$x = f(p, y); p=p(y) $$
$$\therefore [\sin{p}]' =[x]' \implies \cos{p}\frac{dp}{dy} =\frac{dx}{dy}$$
If $$p=\frac{dy}{dx} \implies \frac{1}{p} =\frac{dx}{dy}$$
$$\therefore \cos{p}\frac{dp}{dy}=\frac{1}{p}$$
$$p\cos{p}\frac{dp}{dy}=1$$
$$p\cos{p}dp=dy$$
$$\int p\cos{p}dp=\int dy$$
$$p\sin{p}+\cos{p}+k_1= y+k_2$$
$$ p\sin{p}+\cos{p}+C= y$$
It's at this point where I don't know how to go any further
I have a clue, which would be:
$$y = \arcsin{x} \implies dy = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx$$
$$\therefore p =\frac{dy}{dx} =\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
How could I come up with the solution?

Mathematica:  $$\sqrt{1-x^2}+x \sin ^{-1}(x)+c_1$$

I know the solution, My problem is with the procedure by solving the equation respect to x, I get to this point and I don't know how to go any further $$p,\operatorname{sen}\left(p\right)+\cos\left(p\right)+C= y$$

What is sen(p)?

My bad, sorry sen(p) is $$\sin{p} $$

You've gotten the correct bit up to
\begin{align}
y=p\sin(p)+\cos(p)+C,
\end{align}
but then you've incorrectly written $y=\arcsin(x)$ at the end, when it should be $p=\arcsin(x)$, (the original ODE). Upon substitution you have
\begin{align}
y&=\arcsin(x)\sin(\arcsin(x))+\cos(\arcsin(x))+C\\
&=x\arcsin(x)+\sqrt{1-\sin(\arcsin(x))^2}+C\\
&=x\arcsin(x)+\sqrt{1-x^2}+C.
\end{align}

The second solution,
$$
\begin{cases}
x(p)=\sin p, \\
y(p)=p\sin p+\cos p +C,
\end{cases} \tag{1}
$$
is a solution in parametric form: as $p$ varies, $(x(p),y(p))$ describes a curve in the plane that satisfies the differential equation $\sin y'(x)=x$. Indeed,
$$
\sin y'(x)=\sin\left(\frac{y'(p)}{x'(p)}\right)
=\sin\left(\frac{\sin p+p\cos p-\sin p}{\cos p}\right)=\sin p = x. \tag{2}
$$
It's also possible to show that $(1)$ is equivalent to your first solution by eliminating $p$ in $(1)$:
$$
x=\sin p \implies p=\arcsin x\quad\text{and}\quad \cos p=\sqrt{1-x^2}, \tag{3}
$$
hence
$$
y=x\arcsin x+\sqrt{1-x^2}+C. \tag{4}
$$
